# Can I find out which face is in which vertex groups?

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

I would like to select a face of a mesh and then find out in which vertex group this face is in.

Is there a way to see that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In edit mode, select a vertex: you can read its weights assignements in the N properties panel, item tab, vertex weights (visible only if there are any).

[image]

Comment: great man, thank you!